# Retrieve a nested NSDictionary from property list

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I want to save data in a property list in one view and retrieve it in another view. The structure of the data that I'm saving looks like this:

Key: (NSString) 
Value (NSDictionary)

The `NSDictionary` just contains strings for both keys and values. Whenever a button is pressed, I fire this method to do the saving:

```
- (IBAction)saveRSSItem:(id)sender {

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self dataFilePath]]){
        dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
    }
    else {
        dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    //Create Dictionary to store RSSItem information
    NSMutableDictionary *RSSdictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if (self.selectedItem.title)
        [RSSdictionary setValue:@"title" forKey:self.selectedItem.title];

    if (self.selectedItem.summary)
        [RSSdictionary setValue:@"summary" forKey:self.selectedItem.summary];

    if (self.selectedItem.author)
        [RSSdictionary setValue:@"author" forKey:self.selectedItem.author];

    if (self.selectedItem.date)
        [RSSdictionary setValue:@"date" forKey:self.selectedItem.date];

    if (self.selectedItem.content)
        [RSSdictionary setValue:@"content" forKey:self.selectedItem.content];

    //Add saved RSSItem to dictionary
    [dictionary setValue:RSSdictionary forKey:self.selectedItem.title];

    //Overwrite the updated dictionary in the property list
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[self dataFilePath]];
    [dictionary writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
}
```

When I'm trying to retrieve the data I do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *savedRSSItemsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[self propertyListFilePath]];
NSDictionary *RSSDictionary = [savedRSSItemsDictionary objectForKey:[savedRSSItemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

The first line retrieves the root dictionary. The second line retrieves a the value of the first row in the property list (which is an `NSDictionary`).

However, I can't use the method valueForKey: on `RSSDictionary`. It seems like its not an `NSDictionary`? Any ideas why I can't retrieve an `NSDictionary` when it is in the value field of a property list? Do I need to use `NSPropertySerialization`?

Comment: Sorry for the weird indentations. This is my first post :)

Comment: (a) I suspect you are confusing value & key in your first code fragment, by the values you are passing it looks like you have them the wrong way around. (b) as you provide no clue as to what is in `savedRSSItemsArray` and `indexPath.row` it will be hard for anyone to help with your second code fragment. Have you run your code in the debugger and looked at what `RSSDictionary` gets set to? If it not what you expect work backwards looking at the other variables.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my code. I am mistaking values and keys in the function call. That will most likely solve everything :)

Comment: @PietroRea you can answer your own question and mark as accepted so that other developers can have reference as well

Comment: Did you print the classname? NSLog("%@",[RSSDictionary class]). Gives you a good indication what your dealing with.  If you solved it please answer your own question (or close it). Don't let it sit unanswered.

Comment: One more thing, this is not exactly the way you should move data between controllers. Use delegates to send your data from one to another.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *savedRSSItemsDictionary = [NSDictionary 
          dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[self propertyListFilePath]];
NSDictionary *RSSDictionary = 
    [savedRSSItemsDictionary objectForKey:[savedRSSItemsArray 
                                       objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Is wrong because you are not specifying a proper key.

You should use an NSArray to store your data. Index a dictionary by the value of a field in the dictionary is a bad idea.